# Byte array to BitmapImage WP

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get `BitmapImage` serialization working on **Windows Phone 8**, but it seems that a lot of libraries are missing from the WP SDK compared to desktop C# apps...

Basically I've got a `Byte` array that I need to parse into a `BitmapImage` for displaying, however nothing I could find on the web works... Any help is much appreciated! :)

*Since StackOverflow's algorithm thinks this question is too trivial, I'm just gonna paste the code that I've got working to convert the BitmapImage to a ByteArray*

```
public static Byte[] ImageToByteArray(BitmapImage image)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap
                (image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight);

            Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmMap, ms,
                image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static BitmapImage ByteArraytoBitmap(Byte[] byteArray)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did try using streams beforehand, but I used a `DataReader` instead of a `MemoryStream` :)

Comment: Wich version of framework are you using? I can't found SetSource method in BitmapImage!