# WPF Byte array to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, bitmap

I read all first page results of "Byte array to BitmapImage" and I fount
[Byte array to BitmapImage WP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762747/byte-array-to-bitmapimage-wp)
[byte[] to BitmapImage in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335819/byte-to-bitmapimage-in-silverlight)
the problem is that I code dosen't work for me and I get this error:

> 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' does not contain a
>   definition for 'SetSource' and no extension method 'SetSource'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My main code is:

```
int stride = CoverPhotoBitmap.PixelWidth * 4;
int size = CoverPhotoBitmap.PixelHeight * stride;
byte[] CoverPhotoPixels = new byte[size];
CoverPhotoBitmap.CopyPixels(CoverPhotoPixels, stride, 0);

byte[] HiddenPhotoPixels = new byte[size];
HiddenPhotoBitmap.CopyPixels(HiddenPhotoPixels, stride, 0);
ResultPhotoBitmap = ByteArraytoBitmap(HiddenPhotoPixels);
```

and my method is:

```
public static BitmapImage ByteArraytoBitmap(Byte[] byteArray)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: How you want to use this bitmap, do you want to set it to Image control?

Comment: You want to set the `Source` property instead of calling the `SetSource` method of the Silverlight BitmapImage. Anyway, that won't help, because it required an encoded image buffer (like PNG or JPEG) which you don't have. You'll have to create a `BitmapSource` from the byte array, or write a byte array to a `WriteableBitmap`.

Comment: @Amer Zafar
Yes I want to use it as an Image control

Comment: @Clemens As you see I used the question that Jcl suggest to me and solved my later question, my current question is what is SetSource alternative in WPF.

Answer (score 3):

The example you found appears to have been specific to Silverlight. The exception explains that the method you called(SetSource) does not exist. What you need to do is set the [StreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
public static BitmapImage ByteArraytoBitmap(Byte[] byteArray)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: Now I get this error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
Additional information: No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.